# django - how can i edit the html displayed in a form field?

Tags: html, django

I'm using bootstrap, and i'd like to set the span of some of the elements i have in a form.

so pretty much, instead of:

```
<input id="id_display_name" type="text" name="display_name">
```

i'd like to show

```
<input id="id_display_name" type="text" name="display_name" class="span4">
```

where the initial line was generated by:

```
{{ form.display_name }}
```

how do i stick the new html in?

Comment: read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/)

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

```
display_name = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'span4'})
```

will result in:

```
<input id="id_display_name" type="text" name="display_name" class="span4" />'
```